# Autodesk Forge Viewer how to get a screenshot of the part of a model

Tags: javascript, three.js, screenshot, autodesk-forge

I have for example 20 element Ids and I want to make screenshot of them (like a detail). For that screenshot I would like to have specific dimensions (for example 400x400). My current viewer has different dimensions. Is there some way how to achieve it and return current viewer in original view?

I was trying to do these steps:

1. store current view
2. set viewer dimensions
3. do fitToView(elementIds) - I have tried to manipulate camera, but I am not much familiar with it. Also, I have tried to use `fitToView` but passed elements are sometimes out of the view.
4. getScreenshot(400, 400)
5. restore view

struggling with it so any help would be great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a nice blog post providing more details around the dimensions of screenshots taken from Forge Viewer: https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/more-screenshots.

If that does not help with your use cases, you could also consider having an additional instance of the viewer on your page, sized exactly as the screenshots you'd like to generate, and only load the IDs of elements you need. Here's a simple code that demonstrates the idea: https://github.com/petrbroz/forge-basic-app/commit/f95cb67944830b842955c9599f2e1e4683ff13f0.

Comment: Thank you, it helped I did resize without having to play with the camera. Just question about `fitToView`. After that I have green dot when rotating/panning can I remove it? And is it possible to do `fitToView` and zoom a little bit out to have bigger detail?

Comment: Hmm, the green dot should only be visible when you interpolate to the new camera position over time (in my case I set the `immediate` flag to `true`), to indicate the pivoting point. If it's still appears for you, it might mean that you're taking the screenshot "too early"... in that case we'd probably need to find some other event to wait for, or introduce a hard-coded delay, before the screenshot is captured.

Comment: Regarding the other question (zooming out a little bit), you can definitely adjust the camera settings at any point in time, for example, moving the camera back (in the direction opposite to the camera direction vector). But if you want to customize endpoint of the camera animation, you might be better off using something like `viewer.navigation.setRequestTransition(true, newCameraPos, newCameraTarget, newCameraFov)`.

Comment: I want to do it immediate and then just restore it to the previous state. Regarding that pivot point, I have it disabled and after I call `fitToView` it starts to display on panning/zooming/rotating the model with mouse